# Per-site metas written twice

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, per-site-meta

The sites drop down in the ask question page shows the per-site metas twice. This is an example screenshot.

[image]

I noticed this only affects per-site metas. Meta Stackoverflow is not written twice.

Comment: Well, this meta is not really per-site meta just yet. :)

Comment: How on earth did you decide which meta to post this on??!

Comment: By the way, do the dupes link to the same sites?

Comment: @Shog9 Luckily Meta SO wasnt written twice :). If it was that would be terrific...

Comment: Interesting; the site dropdown for "Your Sites" _does_ work properly. I was able to reproduce this issue, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What a fun bug! It's been fixed as of version 1.0.9. I was already working on editing stuff in this page and got around to this too... I definitely didn't fix this because of the bounty...

Comment: No shame in some bounty hunting... :-)